# SQL server ADO.NET over low bandwidth TCP/IP connection any tips/experience?

Tags: sql-server, ado.net, tcp

Hello we have an SQL server application running over a low bandwith connection.
We use ADO.NET.

I was wondering if anybody has any tips on minimizing traffic over the channel.
Im looking for answers on ADO.NET/SQL-Server specific tips that make it more efficient.
Not obvious answers like "dont fetch many records".

En example for MySql would be "enable comptression=true" in the connection string.
I'm cannot find anything on transport layer compression in SQL server.

Do any of you people have experience with this ?
Are there important do's and dont's that we must know ?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

other than return less data and shorten your query text as much as possible there's not really much you can do.

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap the communication in a Web Service or WCF. And use compression on the data exchanges.

If you can't do this I would use heavy caching. If the application doesn't have to go back to the server often you will in effect be using less bandwidth.
On this note, look at Local Data Cache - Sync.
Maybe this will help: [The Moth - ADO.NET Sync Services](http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/2008/02/adonet-sync-services.html)

Answer (score 0):

I guess that apart from a completely different way of programming there are no things that might help....

Answer (score 0):

the best is to work in the channel (low bandwith connection and use the QoS options to reduce and organize the trafic